# Is there any way to get Nautilus running again when it stops working WITHOUT rebooting?

Tags: nautilus

This happens every couple of weeks, that I attempt to start Nautilus, and am not able to get it running. The only way I have found to get it running again is to reboot the computer.

For a while there, I [reported this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1705864) sometimes when it happened, but stopped reporting it because it doesn't help resolve the issue.

It is difficult to see any opportunity in the near future to reinstall the operating system.

In the meantime, does anybody have any suggestions for getting Nautilus running again in these instances without rebooting the system?

Comment: PS This is what happens when I try to start Nautilus in a terminal. None of this means anything to me.

"too long by 223 characters"

OK

https://pastebin.com/rv10R2NP

Comment: You can run/restart it anytime by running `nautilus` in terminal and those "errors" are typical and can be ignored. The point is: Does it open a Window? If so it's working; if not, there's something wrong and the first comment on your bug report says it all: *It seems there is something wrong with your system or hard-drive.* So, have you checked your drives already? And have you been installing the updates?

Comment: The journal https://launchpadlibrarian.net/330218463/JournalErrors.txt actually mentions several errors with files and a Plex library. So, most likely NOT a bug and not Nautilus fault and just a drive that needs error correction. Please check that first instead of wasting the devs time by posting the same probably-not-a-bug 5 times!

Comment: I use my drives every day. I haven't "checked" them, and don't really know how. Yes, the operating system is completely up-to-date.

OK I would prefer not to waste anybody's time. If there is a drive that needs error correction, how do I check it, and what is the most probably remedy? The OS and applications are on an SSD, and I use an internal magnetic HDD for anything requiring many write cycles.

Comment: PS My pastebin post above shows what happens when I try to run `nautilus`, and that is ALL that happens. Nothing else (such as a Nautilus window appearing) happens.

Comment: You can run `fsck` from a live session. In the installed system you can first check with the Disks utility. That alone may indicate the health status of the disks. If there are errors/warnings that drive needs to be replaced. If, however, it shows it in good or acceptable health then you should check and correct the *logical* errors with the aforementioned command. For more information about the arguments to use it with please type `man fsck` in terminal.

Comment: I'm going to have to admit defeat. Both disks appear fine in  `gnome-disks`, but I was not able to boot into a live USB drive, despite having done so successfully hundreds of times before, so I haven't been able to run `fsck`. Also, `boincmgr` has become unable to start today. These are all signs that I need to reinstall the OS from scratch. In a way, I'm not surprised, because I used the automatic upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, and I know that's somewhat foolhardy. At least it's not necessary to reinstall the OS every year like it was in the old Windows days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked it out.

I couldn't get `nautilus` to start yesterday afternoon. I slept on it, and left the computer running overnight (working on some BOINC tasks), and just came back to it now.

I tried to start `nautilus`, and as expected, the Unity Launcher icon flashed but the application didn't start.

This time, I started `gnome-system-monitor` to see if `nautilus` appeared in the list of current processes. It did. Hmm.

I right-clicked the `nautilus` process, selected "End", and then clicked "End Process". Then I clicked on the Unity Launcher `nautilus` icon, and the application started normally.

I hope this process is 100% repeatable, because it will save me a LOT of time.